# background color in image (firefox)

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, background-color

I do something like that to handle a missing image and replace it by background color

```
<td width="34"><img onError="handleError(this, '#fff', 'fail');" src="'. $profileImg .'" alt="" height="'.$imgHeight.'" /></td>
```

And that's the Javascript function that handles that:

```
      function handleError(elem, colorCode, state){
        if ((typeof(elem.onerror) === 'function' && state === 'fail')  || (elem.width === 0) ){
          elem.style.backgroundColor = colorCode;
          console.log(colorCode);
        }
      }
```

The console.log line shows that firefox goes in there but won't display the background color ...

PS: I tried also using JQuery..

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'd say you can't set a background color to an image... try setting it to the TD instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your image has `alt=""` which means that on error it won't show up at all in standards mode: Images act just like a `<span>` with the alt text inside in standards mode.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that your image's `$imgHeight` is being set to `0`, ultimately causing the image to not be visible on the page.

*However* it's probably not a good idea to use a background as a fallback on the `img` element. Different browsers will handle non-loaded images in different ways (a red cross in IE, for example). You'll probably want to assign a background to the image's container:

```
<td class="imgContainer">
    <img ... />
</td>

td.imgContainer {
    background:#fff;
}
```

Then simply change your `handleError` function to hide the non-loaded image instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Just save as html file and open in any browser)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleError(elem, colorCode, state){
        if ((typeof(elem.onerror) === 'function' && state === 'fail')  || (elem.width === 0) ){
          elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';         
          console.log(colorCode);
        }
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="q">
    <div><img  style="widht:200px;height:200px;disply:block;"onError="handleError(this, '#fff', 'fail');" src="'. $profileImg .'" alt="" height="'.$imgHeight.'" /></div>
</div>
<body>
</html>
```